# How do i implement a time-comsuming task in OnLaunchApplicationAsync for Prism in UWP?

Tags: c#, .net, win-universal-app, windows-10, prism

I am developing UWP with Prism, when app launches, it need to copy a file from InstallLocation to LocalFolder, and make sure the file exists in LocalFolder before navigate to MainPage. Any Idea how can i achieve that?

It seems like OnLaunchApplicationAsync can return a task, but it navigate to MainPage first before the task completed.

```
protected override Task OnLaunchApplicationAsync(LaunchActivatedEventArgs args)
    {
        Task task = new Task(async () =>
        {
            StorageFile dataFile = await Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync("xx.db3");
            await dataFile.CopyAsync(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder, "xx.db3", NameCollisionOption.FailIfExists);
        });

        NavigationService.Navigate("Main", null);
        Window.Current.Activate();

        return task;

        //return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
    }
```

Any helps are appreciated.

Comment: You need to `await` on the outter Task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this?

```
protected override async Task OnLaunchApplicationAsync(LaunchActivatedEventArgs args)
{
    StorageFile dataFile = await Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync("xx.db3");
    await dataFile.CopyAsync(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder, "xx.db3", NameCollisionOption.FailIfExists);

    NavigationService.Navigate("Main", null);
    Window.Current.Activate();
}
```

No need to over complicate things :-)